# GnuCash still being developed for Mac?

Tags: gnucash

Is GnuCash still being developed for Mac? I am installing for 12.4, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. The [GnuCash news page](https://www.gnucash.org/news.phtml) shows that the latest version, 4.10, was released on 27th  March 2022 for Windows, Mac and Linux.